# angularjs 400 bad request with REST service

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, security

I use AngularJs with spring security for authentication & autorization in Spring REST application. I send a request to the server for login,
Here is my angular service :

```
angular.module('workflowService', ['ngResource']).
 factory('Utilisateur', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('rest/user/:action', {}, {
      authenticate: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {'action' : 'authenticate'},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
                }
        },
  }
    );
 });
```

And on the server side I have a Spring MVC Controller as described below :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
  public  @ResponseBody TokenTransfer authenticate(@PathVariable  String username, @PathVariable String password)
{
    System.out.println( " appel authnticate ");
    System.out.println( "username  "+username+"  pass  "+password);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    Authentication authentication = this.authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    /*
     * Reload user as password of authentication principal will be null after authorization and
     * password is needed for token generation
     */
    LdapUserDetails userDetails =(LdapUserDetails) this.userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    return new TokenTransfer(TokenUtils.createToken(userDetails));
}
```

but I'm getting :

> POST http://localhost:8080/springrestprojet/rest/user/authenticate 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Probably you body data is not an application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Have you tried with application/json? You can take a look at chrome dev tools to inspect the request that is being made

Comment: thanks @Paulo Santos for your suggestion. I tried application/json and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. the problem was in PathVariable, there is no parametres in the Path but just FormParam! I just update my code to :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
   public  @ResponseBody TokenTransfer authenticate(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password)
{
//no modification
}
```